# Natural Number Multiset conjecture counter example sought

Tags: number-theory

Consider a multiset of natural numbers:

$$A_n=[a_j]_{j=1..n}$$

in the cases:

$a_j \not=a_k$ for all $j,k \in {\{1,2,3,...,n}\} \land n \gt 1\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(\operatorname{i})$

$a_j \not=a_k$ for **some** $j,k \in {\{1,2,3,...,n}\} \land n \gt 1$ and $a_j \not= 1$ $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,(\operatorname{ii})$

We define the product of all elements of $A_n$ as a function of $n$ as follows:

$$\mathcal P(n)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}a_j$$

If we define  the function $f_k$ as a function of some fixed $x$ to be the raising to a power of $x$ $k-1$ times so for example  :

$$f_1(x)=1$$
$$f_2(x)=x$$
$$f_3(x)=x^x$$
$$f_4(x)=(x^x)^x$$

Then we define a rounding function $\mathcal R$ as:

$$\mathcal R(x)=\cases{\lfloor x \rfloor&${\{x}\} <\frac{1}{2}$\cr \lceil x \rceil&${\{x}\}\geq\frac{1}{2} $\cr}$$

where ${\{x}\}$ is the fractional part of $x$

We have that for any $A_n$ as previously defined,

$$\mathcal R\Biggl(f_j\Bigl(\frac{1}{\mathcal P(n)}\Bigr)\Biggr) \in {\{0,1}\}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\mathcal R\Biggl(f_j\Bigl(\frac{1}{\mathcal P(n)}\Bigr)\Biggr)}{n} \in {\Biggl\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{9}}\Biggr\}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2)$$

$(1)$ is clearly true seeing that the sequence in $j$ is always a binary alternating sequence, But this does not explain the result of $(2)$, however it is supported by the results like:

$$\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty}\Biggr(\sum^{N}_{n=1}\frac{(1+(-1)^n)}{2N}\Biggl)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty}\Biggr(\sum^{N}_{n=0}\frac{(1+(-1)^n)}{2N}\Biggl)=\frac{1}{2}$$

So the proof will of course require the infinite, because we need to establish that it is true for any such $A_n$, which I think I will probably not be capable enough to do, so a counter example is actually a  happy thing here I think

EDIT:

The counterexamples should occur as an example for $n=12$, as we expect sums like $\frac{6}{11},\frac{8}{13},\frac{9}{15}$ and so on to occur.

Comment: If $n=1$ then the sum in $(2)$ is empty, hence equal to $0$. Also for $A_2=[2,2]$ the expression in $(2)$ equals $0$. In fact, identity $(1)$ immediately implies that the sum in identity $(2)$ must be an *integer* between $0$ and $n-1$, inclusive.

Comment: ah right the first bit was a typo I've fixed

Comment: and the second was also a typo I'm sorry about that

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that for $A_2=[2,2]$ you get $0$.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the condition of uniqueness for $A_n$ which ive done there also

Comment: Then it is not a multiset, but just a set.

Comment: Several counter examples exist for non unique multisets $[1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1]$ will produce $\frac{7}{9}$

Comment: Ok sure but there seems to be a stronger condition allowing multisets which I've tried to describe in the final edit

Comment: I'm very sorry about that it was a very lazy post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

counterexample $A_n=[6554,5521,1862,3070,1200,5494,312,3301,9623,2333,9813,9338]$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\mathcal R\Biggl(f_j\Bigl(\frac{1}{\mathcal P(n)}\Bigr)\Biggr)}{n} =\frac{6}{11}$$

The actual expression for the sum above for multisets that adhere to the condition $(\operatorname{ii})$ is:

$$\sum _{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{j+1}+1}{n}}=
\cases{\frac{1}{2}&$n \in  {\{2k-1:k\in \mathbb N}\} $\cr \frac{1}{2}{\frac {n}{n-1}}&$n \in {\{2k:k\in \mathbb N}\} $\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

By elementary calculus we have $f_j(x)\geq\tfrac12$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and all $j\geq2$. It follows that for $j\geq2$ and for all $n\geq0$ we have
$$\mathcal{R}\left(f_j\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)=1.$$
Of course it is clear that
$$\mathcal{R}\left(f_1\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)
=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }\mathcal{P}(n)\leq2,\\
0&\text{ if }\mathcal{P}(n)>2,
\end{cases}$$
and that $\mathcal{P}(n)\leq2$ if and only if $a_i\in\{1,2\}$ for all $i$. It follows that
$$\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{R}\left(f_j\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)
=\begin{cases}
\tfrac{n-1}{n}&\text{ if }\ \forall i:\,a_i\in\{1,2\}\\
\tfrac{n-2}{n}&\text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}$$
In particular, counterexamples to your claim $(2)$ are easily constructed. Take for example $A_3=\{1,2,3\}$. Then $\mathcal{P}(3)=6$ and
$$\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{R}\left(f_j\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)
=\frac13\left(\lfloor f_1(\tfrac16)\rfloor+\lfloor f_2(\tfrac16)\rfloor\right)
=\frac13(0+1)=\frac13.$$
There are of course also the obvious counterexamples with $n=1$; in this case the sum is empty and so
$$\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{R}\left(f_j\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)=0.$$

Comment: Sorry is the $f_1$ a typo?

Comment: Which $f_1$ where?

Comment: $$\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{R}\left(f_1\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)
=\begin{cases}
\tfrac{n-1}{n}&\text{ if }\ \forall i:\,a_i\in\{1,2\}\\
\tfrac{n-2}{n}&\text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Adam Yes, fixed.

Comment: Ok so yes I agree with the counter example without the exclusion of $a_j=1$, but I'm not sure how you were able to make the assertion regarding elementary calculus can you please explain this part for me thankyou very much for taking the time to look at my problem by the way

Comment: And I believe there is several examples for which $\mathcal{R}\left(f_j\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)=0$ and it follows that $\mathcal{R}\left(f_{j+1}\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)}\right)\right)=1$ and vice versa as I stated, it is always an alternating sequence

Comment: First show that $f_2(x)=x^x\geq\tfrac12$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then prove that for $x,y\in[0,1]$ you have $x\leq x^y$. Then it follows by induction that $f_j(x)\geq\tfrac12$ for all $j\geq2$.

Comment: As for your last comment; my answer shows that the sequence is *not* always alternating. In fact it is *never* alternating; if $\mathcal{R}(f_j(x))=1$ then $\mathcal{R}(f_{j+1}(x))=1$.

Comment: $[ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}}
 \right) ^{ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{{\frac {{33600}^{{\frac
{33599}{33600}}}}{33600}}}}}, \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{
 \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{{\frac {{33600}^{{\frac{33599}{
33600}}}}{33600}}}}, \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{{\frac {{33600
}^{{\frac{33599}{33600}}}}{33600}}},{\frac {{33600}^{{\frac{33599}{
33600}}}}{33600}},{\frac{1}{33600}},1]
$

Comment: for $A_n=[8,6,2,7,10,2,4,6]$

Comment: Is the sequence in reverse order for $f_j(\frac{1}{\mathcal{P}(n)})$

Comment: $\left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) 
^{ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{{\frac {{33600}^{{\frac{33599}{
33600}}}}{33600}}}}} \approx 0
$

Comment: $ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) ^{ \left( {\frac{1}{33600}} \right) 
^{{\frac {{33600}^{{\frac{33599}{33600}}}}{33600}}}}
 \approx 1$

Comment: I think you will find that the conditions $(\operatorname{ii})$ allow for a lot of multisets and it is very strong as far as I have searched, however of course as you know one counterexample will be sufficient to disprove but an infinite number of examples are required for proof